# Where to access the notification in GitLab?

Tags: notifications, gitlab

Someone answer my commit and I get it via email, but I don't know where to get it via the web interface.
[image]

In the documetation [Paging and notifications | GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/operations/incident_management/paging.html#paging-and-notifications) it only talks about Slack and email notification